# how to capture multiple optional groups

Tags: python, regex

This is my string:

> 2015-12-07T14:05:14+02:00 1.1.1.1 <13>1 2015-12-07T14:05:13+02:00
>   my_server - - - - 2.2.2.2

I'm trying to capture "1.1.1.1", "my_server" and "2.2.2.2". However I need "1.1.1.1" and "my_server" part should be optional. I wrote some regex and it does match everything when my test string is as above. But it doesn't match when my test string is like this:

> 2.2.2.2

So here is my regex:

```
(?:(?P<server_ip>[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}).*?(?:(?P<server_name>\S*?)
- - - - )).*?(?P<remote_ip>[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3})
```

I am testing the regex [here](http://bit.ly/1PYQh9i). Can someone help me out?

Comment: why not just make the capturing groups that are optional optional by adding a `?` after them?

Comment: If they are optional, what does the input string look like?

Comment: @timgeb Stupid me! I did make it work with your way like [this](http://bit.ly/1YYs8B8). I can resolve this if you answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make any of your capturing groups optional (more precise: match zero or one times) by simply adding a `?` after the closing parenthesis. E.g.

```
(someregex)?
```

Do this for your groups that are supposed to capture  "1.1.1.1" and "my_server".